# Returning HTML webpages e.g. with Soap-UI?

Tags: web-applications, soapui

I am building a web-application, to which you navigate to through an external web-application I do not control. This means I cannot "launch" my webpage without somehow simulating the external web-application.

What would be my options? Can I e.g. use Soap-UI to request a URL -page with some context, and Soap-UI then renders my HTML response by opening up a web-browser?

Comment: You mean mocking html response?

Comment: Actually, the other way around :) I need to mock the external web-app somehow, which is the initiator of the url request.